# Scott/Lawson topology for function space domain

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, denotational-semantics, topology

Given two domains, $D_1$, $D_2$, 
already equipped with Scott (or Lawson) topology, 
the product domain $D=D_1\times D_2$ 
has the Tychonoff product topology, e.g., 
[Mathematical Theory of Domains, page 124](https://books.google.com/books?id=epb39s2wgt0C&pg=PA124).

I can't seem to find a similar discussion of the function space topology 
for $D=[D_1\rightarrow D_2]$, 
though I assume it's well-known. 
Can someone explain it and/or give a reference which discusses it?

More generally, 
if you have a general domain equation 
$D=F(D_1,\ldots,D_n)$, 
where $F(\cdot)$ is built up from $D_1,\ldots,D_n$ 
by usual operations like product and function space, 
what can you say about $D$'s Scott/Lawson topology?
In particular, how can you construct the open sets of $D$
from the open sets of $D_1,\ldots,D_n$?

Comment: @Tom, domains are part of programming language semantics. Dana Scott invented them to provide a semantic for lambda calculus.

Comment: The references I use when I want to look up something is G. Gierz, K. H. Hofmann, K. Keimel, J. D. Lawson, M. Mislove, D. S. Scott, [Continuous Lattices and Domains](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xPF9Hb7DPLgC) and Samson Abramsky
and Achim Jung [Domain Theory](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/handy1.pdf). For topology vs. order theory S. Vickers [Topology via Logic](https://books.google.ca/books?id=VvCKDnCrZCgC) is very good.

Comment: It has been years since I have looked at these but generally when thinking about domains I always find it useful to think about them in terms of information: so intuitively the topology of $[D \to E]$ should be similar to the topology of $D^{op} \times E$. I will check Vicker's book when I have time (or you can do it yourself if you don't want to wait :).

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks for the hint to consider $D^{op}\times E$, which likely solves the problem (of specifying the open sets of $[D\rightarrow E]$ in terms of those of $D$ and $E$). I already have print copies of all three references you suggested (Handbook Volume 3 containing the Abramsky and Jung extended article, although your online version is an "expanded and extended" version).  So I'll check them all myself -- certainly a worthwhile exercise regardless of reason:). P.S. and thanks for adding the tags (funny, I couldn't find a domain theory tag when I looked).

Comment: I'd thought I'd just missed something obvious, and maybe it is, but I'm still not seeing how $D^{op}\times E\sim [D\rightarrow E]$, where I'm taking it you mean the usual (usual to me, anyway) $\sqsubseteq\Leftrightarrow\sqsupseteq$ for $D^{op}$. At first blush, doesn't seem cardinality-wise right, so I guess I'm still missing what you're saying.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for cstheory or for math.stackexchange.

Comment: Good question!  The question is on-topic here, but John Forkosh, if you'd like to see this migrated to CSTheory or Math, you can click "flag" to flag it for moderator attention and ask that it be migrated.

Comment: Thanks, J.E.Pin and D.W. I'll research the question a little more before flagging for migration. Doesn't seem like it should be all that hard -- more like an end-of-chapter problem in some senior undergraduate or first-year graduate textbook. But I couldn't set it up myself in five minutes, so googled it and then asked here. I'll first look around some more, then give it ~five hours with pencil and paper, and if still failing, edit the question with my attempted solution and specific stumbling block, and then request migration. Thanks again.